# How would I say: The cat thought a snake appeared?

Tags: grammar

I currently wrote this as:  猫は蛇が現れたと思た. The cat thought  a snake appeared.

Is this correct ?

Comment: Could you name what exactly you want to ask? Tense? Quotative? Topic? I think this would be put closed as proofreading or something if like this.

Answer (score 8):

> 「猫は蛇が現れたと**思た**.」

This sentence is good except for the last word and the non-Japanese period.　Excellent use of 「は」 and 「が」.

> 「[猫]{ねこ}は[蛇]{へび}が[現]{あらわ}れたと[思]{おも}**った**。」 is the corect sentence.

Other possibilities:

「猫はヘビが[出]{で}てきたのかと思った。」

「猫はヘビが出てきたと思った。」

「猫はヘビが現れたのかと思った。」

Answer (score 4):

Your sentence looks fine except that 思た should be [思]{おも}った.